# Problem with Ajax and MySQL to check whether a username is already taken

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I tested and I confirmed that I am able to get the value from the input box by alerting the value inside the function checkusername. I also tested the php file individually for the query, and it worked. I really think the problem is either transferring the value from my fist page to another page (thoughtverifier.php) or getting the value from "thoughtverifier.php"

```
<script>
 function checkusername(puser){
   var AJAXObject;
   if (puser == "" )
  return ;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
 AJAXObject =new XMLHttpRequest();
   else 
   AJAXObject =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
   AJAXObject.onreadystatechange= function(){
   if (AJAXObject.readyState ==4 && AJAXObject.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('txtuser').innerHTML=AJAXObject.responseText
    }

    AJAXObject.open("GET","thoughtverifier.php?puse="+puser,true);
    AJAXObject.send();
  }
</script>
```

And the HTML code-

```
    <Form method ="post" name="regform" id ="regform" action="thoughtshomepage.php">

        <table class="alligm">
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtuser" onchange="checkusername(this.value)"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </Form>
```

and the PHP involved- I correctly connected to my SQL and this the rest

```
        $q = $_GET['puse'];//i have doubt here

        $strSQL =" SELECT * FROM `tableuser` WHERE username = '$q'" ;

        mysqli_query($con,$strSQL) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rowcount > 0) {
            echo "user exists";
        }
        else {
            echo "no";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also there is no jQuery in your code. If there were, you could use `$.get()` instead of XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ii am not getting a response because there is no output like user "exist" or "no"

Comment: Lastly https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I have Jquery i specified in the top<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.4.1.js'></script>

Comment: So why use XMLHttpRequest ? You are not using ANY jQuery in the posted code

Comment: And change  `$q = $_GET['puse'];` to `$q = urldecode($_GET['puse']);`

Comment: I am just testing the concept then. But appreciate your concern

Comment: You have typo near `AJAXObject,status` change `,` by `.` i.e: ` `AJAXObject.status` ,also does this id i.e : `txtuser` exist or not in your html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for ajax calls which is easy and lesser amount of code.

you can try this:

```
$.get('/thoughtverifier.php?puse='+puser,
  function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
  if (data) {
    document.getElementById('txtuser').innerHTML=data
  }
});
```

Comment: i couldn't get it though but very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#regform").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    $.get(this.action+"?puse="+encodeURIComponent($("[name=txtuser]").val()),function(result) {
      $("[name=txtuser]").closest("tr").find("td").html(result==="no"?"User name OK":"User name taken");
    })
  });
});
```

and use decode on puse on your server

Also test to see what you get if you call

`yourserver.com/thoughtshomepage.php?puse=exsting%20user`

Comment: localhost/thoughtshomepage.php?puse=exsting%20user  and was directed to my homepage. But after I tried your solution for every submit it says username taken

Comment: So the PHP is not passing "no" back. It redirects to your homepage. Perhaps you need $.post and $_POST

Comment: You of course need to change `exsting%20user` to `John%20Doe` which exists in your database

Comment: i replaced $q = $_GET['puse']; with $q = $_POST['puse']; but still it redirects to homepage.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the script but to do with your server - you need to know what your are doing on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have element with id "txtuser" for  `document.getElementById('txtuser').innerHTML`, so maybe you can edit your html to:

```
<Form method ="post" name="regform" id ="regform" action="thoughtshomepage.php">
    <table class="alligm">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtuser" onchange="checkusername(this.value)">
                <span id="txtuser"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be in the way you're referring to the contents of the text box in the JS function.

You have stated:

```
document.getElementById('txtuser').innerHTML=AJAXObject.responseText
```

But it should be:

```
document.getElementById('txtuser').value=AJAXObject.responseText
```

This is because as per the DOM, a text box's contents is not referenced using innerHTML. If you want to use innerHTML, use a DIV instead of a text box.